# How to set language of Message in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I hope to see the Message information to display in English within Android Studio, how can I configure that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find an answer on this forum, here are some other forums where you
can discuss the problem with advanced developers specifically using Android Studio :

- [Google for Android Developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers)
- [xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/tools/android-studio)
- [IntelliJ IDEA Users](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) (as Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a utility do that? or is there a simple way ?

Comment: I haven't found any utility for that. If you need help, post your resources_en.jar file and I'll have a look.

Comment: Thanks! my resources_en.jar is at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209352/resources_en.jar

Comment: And more, I found many .properties files such as CommonBundle.properties is english, so I don't know where I need change the language of the text

Comment: Sorry - I now understood: The link I found related to how to change the interface from English to another language by translating the interface text, which is the opposite of what you want. I can see in your capture that the non-English part is issued by NanoFileUpload which seems to be a file-upload component. Are you sure that this text is not coming from some web server?

Comment: Thanks! When I compile a project which include NanoFileUpload component in Android Studio, I get the error message, the error message is displayed with Chinese. I hope to paste the error message in website, there are only a few people can understand Chinese, so I hope to the error message generated by Android Studio displayed as English. How can I do?

Comment: BTW, my OS is Chinese Windows 7 (64)

Comment: As not many people here can read it, can you translate the Chinese part to English? And does this happen only with NanoFileUpload?

Comment: Many error message of other projects are displayed as Chinese in Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have installed  `resources_*.jar` files for other languages? If yes, you could try to replace them by  a copy of `resources_en.jar` (while keeping the old version as backup).

Comment: Thanks! I don't install any resources_*.jar files for other languages, there are two resource files resources.jar and resources_en.jar in the folder \lib

Comment: Sorry that my ideas did not help. I converted my answer above to links to some forums where you could find advanced users of Android Studio who will be better qualified to help. I suggest that we both delete all our comments on this answer, as they did not help in finding a solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! but I suggest that we keep these comments because it make the question more clear.

Comment: OK - as you like.